# What is the equivalent script in powershell for image-copy-extension extension from Azure CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I need to create a VM in `locationA` from Image `ImageB` which is in `locationB` using powershell. Since I'm not able to do it I'm trying to create a copy of `ImageB` into `locationA`, so that it will easy for me to create the VM.

I have searched for scripts to copy the images and got many results. I found one particular [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2018/01/18/azure-cli-image-copy-extension-allows-you-to-copy-virtual-machine-images-between-regions-with-just-one-command/) which has simple script to copy images. But it is AzureCLI cmdlets. I need powershell scripts to do the job as the tool I'm using understands only powershell scripts.

I have searched for an equivalent powershell script but couldn't find any.Can anyone help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script to copy the image. You could create a snapshot and copy it to anther region, then create the image.

Create a snapshot:

```
<# -- Create a snapshot of the OS (and optionally data disks) from the generalized VM -- #>
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vmName
$disk = Get-AzureRmDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Name
$snapshot = New-AzureRmSnapshotConfig -SourceUri $disk.Id -CreateOption Copy -Location $region

$snapshotName = $imageName + "-" + $region + "-snap"

New-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Snapshot $snapshot -SnapshotName $snapshotName
```

Copy the snapshot:

```
# Create the name of the snapshot, using the current region in the name.
$snapshotName = $imageName + "-" + $region + "-snap"

# Get the source snapshot
$snap = Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName

# Create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) for the source snapshot
$snapSasUrl = Grant-AzureRmSnapshotAccess -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName -DurationInSecond 3600 -Access Read

# Set up the target storage account in the other region
$targetStorageContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName).Context
New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $imageContainerName -Context $targetStorageContext -Permission Container

# Use the SAS URL to copy the blob to the target storage account (and thus region)
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $snapSasUrl.AccessSAS -DestContainer $imageContainerName -DestContext $targetStorageContext -DestBlob $imageBlobName
Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState -Container $imageContainerName -Blob $imageBlobName -Context $targetStorageContext -WaitForComplete

# Get the full URI to the blob
$osDiskVhdUri = ($targetStorageContext.BlobEndPoint + $imageContainerName + "/" + $imageBlobName)

# Build up the snapshot configuration, using the target storage account's resource ID
$snapshotConfig = New-AzureRmSnapshotConfig -AccountType StandardLRS `
                                            -OsType Windows `
                                            -Location $targetRegionName `
                                            -CreateOption Import `
                                            -SourceUri $osDiskVhdUri `
                                            -StorageAccountId "/subscriptions/${sourceSubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/${storageAccountName}"

# Create the new snapshot in the target region
$snapshotName = $imageName + "-" + $targetRegionName + "-snap"
$snap2 = New-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName -Snapshot $snapshotConfig
```

Create the image:

```
<# -- In the second subscription, create a new Image from the copied snapshot --#>
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $targetSubscriptionId

$snap = Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName

$imageConfig = New-AzureRmImageConfig -Location $destinationRegion

Set-AzureRmImageOsDisk -Image $imageConfig `
                        -OsType Windows `
                        -OsState Generalized `
                        -SnapshotId $snap.Id

New-AzureRmImage -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
                 -ImageName $imageName `
                 -Image $imageConfig
```

For more details, refer to this [link](https://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/copy-managed-images/).

Comment: hey thanks for reply. In this step --> # Set up the target storage account in the other region , in $storageAccountName , should I give the name of storage account from source region or destination region?

Comment: @CrazyCoder destination region.