# How to move an azure VM image to a different location

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

I have an azure VM image with a managed disk in east US and I want to move/copy it to West Europe.

Is there an easy way to do it?

I saw that there's an azure cli extension called az-image-copy but it doesn't work for me because it outputs an error which says that it can't find the OS disk (even though the resource ID is correct and I can see it in the azure portal)

> ERROR: Resource ServerLinux_OsDisk_1_c208679747734937b10a1525aa84a7d7 is not found

So is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use azure powershell to copy the managed images, create a snapshot and copy it to anther region, then create the image. Here is a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52658353/what-is-the-equivalent-script-in-powershell-for-image-copy-extension-extension-f/52658992#52658992).

Create a snapshot:

```
<# -- Create a snapshot of the OS (and optionally data disks) from the generalized VM -- #>
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vmName
$disk = Get-AzureRmDisk -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DiskName $vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Name
$snapshot = New-AzureRmSnapshotConfig -SourceUri $disk.Id -CreateOption Copy -Location $region

$snapshotName = $imageName + "-" + $region + "-snap"

New-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Snapshot $snapshot -SnapshotName $snapshotName
```

Copy the snapshot:

```
# Create the name of the snapshot, using the current region in the name.
$snapshotName = $imageName + "-" + $region + "-snap"

# Get the source snapshot
$snap = Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName

# Create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) for the source snapshot
$snapSasUrl = Grant-AzureRmSnapshotAccess -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName -DurationInSecond 3600 -Access Read

# Set up the target storage account in the other region
$targetStorageContext = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName).Context
New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $imageContainerName -Context $targetStorageContext -Permission Container

# Use the SAS URL to copy the blob to the target storage account (and thus region)
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $snapSasUrl.AccessSAS -DestContainer $imageContainerName -DestContext $targetStorageContext -DestBlob $imageBlobName
Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState -Container $imageContainerName -Blob $imageBlobName -Context $targetStorageContext -WaitForComplete

# Get the full URI to the blob
$osDiskVhdUri = ($targetStorageContext.BlobEndPoint + $imageContainerName + "/" + $imageBlobName)

# Build up the snapshot configuration, using the target storage account's resource ID
$snapshotConfig = New-AzureRmSnapshotConfig -AccountType StandardLRS `
                                            -OsType Windows `
                                            -Location $targetRegionName `
                                            -CreateOption Import `
                                            -SourceUri $osDiskVhdUri `
                                            -StorageAccountId "/subscriptions/${sourceSubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/${storageAccountName}"

# Create the new snapshot in the target region
$snapshotName = $imageName + "-" + $targetRegionName + "-snap"
$snap2 = New-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName -Snapshot $snapshotConfig
```

Create the image:

```
<# -- In the second subscription, create a new Image from the copied snapshot --#>
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $targetSubscriptionId

$snap = Get-AzureRmSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName

$imageConfig = New-AzureRmImageConfig -Location $destinationRegion

Set-AzureRmImageOsDisk -Image $imageConfig `
                        -OsType Windows `
                        -OsState Generalized `
                        -SnapshotId $snap.Id

New-AzureRmImage -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
                 -ImageName $imageName `
                 -Image $imageConfig
```

For more details, refer to this [link](https://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/copy-managed-images/).

Answer (score 0):

If the resources are under the same subscription then you can get move resources to from the Resource Group 01 (East Us) to the Resource Group 02 (West Europe). 
For your help you can check these documents:

[Move Managed Disks and VMs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/move-managed-disks-and-vms-now-available/)

[Move resources to new resource group or subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources)

[Copy managed disks in the same subscription or different subscription with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-windows-powershell-sample-copy-managed-disks-to-same-or-different-subscription)

[Migrating Azure IaaS solutions using MigAz](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2016/07/16/migrating-azure-iaas-solutions-from-asm-to-arm-using-migaz/)

The last link is about the MigAz tool, which allow to migrate resources on Azure.